# Define selected menu option based in a URL property

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a menu in razor View MVC:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Criar Nova", "Create", new { tipo = Request.Params["tipo"] })
@Html.ActionLink("Listar Todas", "Index", new { tipo = @ViewBag.ENTIDADE_LISTAR_TODAS })
@Html.ActionLink("Listar Expedidoras", "Index", new { tipo = @ViewBag.ENTIDADE_LISTAR_TIPO_EXP })
@Html.ActionLink("Listar Destinatárias", "Index", new { tipo = @ViewBag.ENTIDADE_LISTAR_TIPO_DEST })
```

The URL of the View is like www.xxx.com?tipo=YYY

How can I set a style like bold in the ActionLink text based in the YYY value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to strip the url and get your string variable you could assign the css class with your bold in the html link itself.

```
<head>
   <style>
   .activeMenu{font-wieght:bold;}
   </style>
</head>

@Html.ActionLink("Criar Nova", "Create", new { tipo = Request.Params["tipo"] }, new { @class = "activeMenu"})
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but how can I made the Request.Params value to the correct option to insert the class property?